# Is there any mechanical assistance in converting from Rails 1.x to 2.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade

I've got a Rails 1.2.3 application that I need to launch on a new server, which has Rails 2.1.0

As I expected, just putting up the 1.2.3 code and trying to run with 2.1 fails.

I don't know enough about Rails to know what things to change myself, so my current plan is to generate a new project using 2.1.0 and then move the code myself manually.

Obviously, if there's an easier way to do this, I'd be very happy to use it.

Thanks in advance, and apologies if I'm missing the bleeping obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get any error messages, check the development.log and production.log. I have tried the same thing but with no problems.